# Substituting values of a matrix

Tags: matlab, pixel, substitution

Say I have the following two matrices:

```
>> x = [1 4 3; 6 4 3; 6 9 3; 2 4 3; 5 4 0; 5 3 1; 6 4 7];
>> y = [0 0 1; 1 1 0; 1 1 0; 0 1 1; 0.2 0.8 0.54; 1 1 1; 0 0 0];
```

Where you can think of `x` as some image, and `y` the **degree of membership** of of each element of `x` to some region of interest.

Say I set those elements in `x` that have degree of membership = 1 to `1` and the other elements to `0` as follows:

```
x = zeros(size(y));
x(y==1) = 1;
```

In which case I will have the following output:

```
     0     0     1
     1     1     0
     1     1     0
     0     1     1
     0     0     0
     1     1     1
     0     0     0
```

Now, for the elements of `0`, how can I substitute their values with the value of `y` in the corresponding location?

Thanks.

Comment: You will likely get more help if you accept the answers you get.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

`x(x==0)=y(x==0);`

Ans:

```
x =

     0         0    1.0000
1.0000    1.0000         0
1.0000    1.0000         0
     0    1.0000    1.0000
0.2000    0.8000    0.5400
1.0000    1.0000    1.0000
     0         0         0
```

Comment: That has nothing to do with the code I suppose... I think the function is not on the MATLAB search path...