# What do these statements mean in matlab

Tags: matlab

I came about those two statements in `matlab` and here would like to ask about what the syntax means.

`area_xy = (f > 1);`

`area_xyz = (f == 1);`

Does that mean for instance that `area_xy` contains the elements of some vecotr `f` such that those elements are `> 1`?

Thanks.

Comment: What have you done to figure this out for yourself ?  Matlab is an interactive numerical computing environment, why don't you try some interaction ?

Comment: Check out [this doc](http://www.mathworks.com/company/newsletters/articles/Matrix-Indexing-in-MATLAB/matrix.html) especially the part on **logical** indexing.

Comment: You have used that yourself in a [question that you asked](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15044667/substituting-values-of-a-matrix/15045059#15045059). `x(y==1) = 1;`. Another example [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15045496/undefined-function-or-method-image-with-membership-values-for-input-argumen) `x(x==0) = y(x==0)`

Answer (score 3):

In MATLAB, comparison operators (e.g., `>`, `==`, `<=`) always give a boolean result: `1` for true, and `0` for false.  Further, if one of the operands is a vector, or both the operands are vectors of the same size, then the comparison is done *element-wise* and the result is a vector of boolean results.  So for example:

```
x = (1 < 2)     % x contains 1 since this is true
x = (1 == 2)    % x contains 0 since this is false

a = [ 1 3 5 3 2 ]
x = (a < 3)         % x contains [ 1 0 0 0 1 ], since 1 and 2 are less than 3 but the others are not

a = [ 1 3 5 2 3 ]
b = [ 1 4 2 2 4 ]
x = (a == b)        % x contains [ 1 0 0 1 0 ], since elements 1 and 4 are the same in each
```

So, `area_xy` does *not* contains the elements of `f` which satisfy the inequality; instead it contains a *mask* which contains `1` where the inequality was true and `0` where it was not.  You can obtain the actual values of `f` which satisfy this by evaluating:

```
f(area_xy)
```